# update-grub for /dev/sdx

Tags: grub2

I have two Hard-Drives (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`).

When I do `update-grub`, it would consider either `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

Is there any way to do `update-grub` just for `/dev/sda` ?

**UPDATE**

I've tried :

```
sudo update-grub /dev/sda
```

Output : (Considered `sdb`)

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Arch on /dev/sdb1 # << Founded Arch on sdb !!!!
done
```